# -webkit-animation-name css selector bug

Tags: css, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools, css-animations

Is this a bug? On safari and chrome `-webkit-animation-name` doesn't seem to override properly. The following CSS should cause a ghastly flashing effect on the `h1` tag called `title` but the animation fails to run;

```
@-webkit-keyframes flash2 {
    0% { background-color: red; }
    100% { background-color: blue; }
}
@-ms-keyframes flash2 {
    0% { background-color: red; }
    100% { background-color: blue; }
}
h1 {
    /* this breaks the animation on chrome,safari */
    -webkit-animation-name: none;
    -ms-animation-name: none;
}
h1#title {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: flash2;

    -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-name: flash2;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DQ96d/5/
Is this a bug?

Either way, I wanted to document what I've discovered since it cost me a lot of time to resolve. The main reason I couldn't see this at first was because the inspector in chrome (F12) indicated that the css selectors had properly prioritised and `-webkit-animation-name` was indeed showing `flash2`. HOWEVER - the animation fails to run.

Hopefully this may help someone else. The workaround would seem to be that you can't have that property in more than one CSS selector. Curiously, if you list it twice in one rule it doesn't break.

Comment: Please report the bug at http://crbug.com/new. PS. Your first `ms` prefix is missing a hyphen.

Comment: For that matter, you don't even need the `-ms-` prefix - it is not used by any stable version of IE.

Comment: IE10 seems to accept the -ms prefix. The demo works as I'd expect in IE10 (as long as I have the missing hypen).

Comment: I already filed a bug using Tools->Report an issue... in chrome (I did something similar in Safari). Does that go through the Chromium project or will it dissappear into the corporate marketing machine instead?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been "it is not required by any stable version of IE". IE10 accepts the prefix, but it also accepts it without the prefix, so it's OK to remove the prefix entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'none' try giving the h1 a dummy name, like:

```
-webkit-animation-name: test;
```

Seems to work ok like this.

Comment: Wierd. So 'none' sounds like a 'special' (unfortunate) code path.